# issue integrating php with sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-express, php-5.5

It's my first time integrating php with SQL Server. The SQL server in context is located on another physical computer on the same LAN. I'm using the configuration explained below:

- **php**: version 5.5
- **SQL Server**: 2005 Express
- **php drivers**: sqlsrv 3.2
- **thread safety**: disabled

I'm being faced with the error below:

> Connection could not be established.
>  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access
>   the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native
>   Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access
>   the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native
>   Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified ) ).

The code being used follows below:

```
<?php
$serverName = "TESTSERV\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Can anyone guide me on what needs to be done here in order to successfully connect to the database?

Comment: Where is your code which doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @SergeiKovalenko. Thanks for your reply. code has been updated in the question.

Comment: You were missing the ODBC driver for the version of SQL Server you tried to connect to. Have you tried downloading the driver from the URL included?

Comment: Yes I've downloaded sqlsrv3.2 which contain the drivers for php version 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP requires installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client as you can read in error message. Only downloading of extension dll is not enough. You can read more in official [System Requirements (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx).

> Versions 3.2 and 3.1 require Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 (or higher) for SQL Server. To download the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for PHP for SQL Server, see Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
>
> If you are using the SQLSRV driver, sqlsrv_client_info will return information about which version of SQL Server Native Client is being used by the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server. If you are using the PDO_SQLSRV driver, you can use PDO::getAttribute to discover the version.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Download, install and try to refresh your testing page.

Comment: Thanks Kba, you're right your answer did the trick. Is there any way where I can avoid installing server 2012 ? I'd like to avoid having 2 different versions of SQL server (even though they might be on separate servers).

Comment: I dont understand. If you install Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 (from link above) or Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ([from here for example](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php)), you are not forced to installing another instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks kba. Both the SQL Server 2012 Native Client (installed on the machine running the php server), aswell as the odbc driver allowed me to properly connect to the SQL Server gracefuly :). Thanks again.

Comment: I've downloaded and installed MS ODBC driverer 11 (amd64) on my Win7 64bit.But it stills issue same error message. What's wrong?

Comment: In the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx page, it said  3.2 only needs MS ODBC driver 11 but actually we need to install SQL Server Native Client of 2012, too.